# jQuery: Faking Fixed position with .scroll() function laggs in Firefox & Safari

Tags: jquery, scroll, safari, cross-browser, css-position

For a **one-page-slide-site** I wanted headers of each slide to be fixed position, to do this I had to using jQuery `.scroll()` function, since `position:fixed` does't care about the overflow of each `.slide`. This works just fine in Chrome, but in Firefox (sometimes) and in Safari it laggs causing the div with `.fake-fixed` to jump (well because of overflow, only the `<h3>` appears to jump). Is there any better way to do this, or another workaround that would give smoother scroll-effect in Safari?

Html:

```
<body>
<section id="slide-1" class="slide">
  <div class="title fake-fixed">
    <h2>SLIDE 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
        <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</section>
<section id="slide-2" class="slide">
  <div class="title fake-fixed">
    <h2>SLIDE 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
        <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</section>
<section id="slide-3" class="slide">
  <div class="title fake-fixed">
    <h2 class="">SLIDE 3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
        <!-- Content -->
  </div>
</section>
</body>
```

JS:

```
function fakeFixed(){
        $fakeFixed = jQuery('.fake-fixed');
        $window = jQuery(window);
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
            $fakeFixed.each(function(){
                $this = jQuery(this);
                    $this.css('margin-top', $window.scrollTop() - $this.parent().position().top);
                        console.log();
                });
            });
    } //cLose fakeFixed

    fakeFixed();
```

Here's a fiddle to illustrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/popmouth/f61jseks/1/

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue @carl. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No not yet I'm afraid :/